# keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DNSName components must begin with a letter << Command failed, code: 1

Tags: jmeter, jmx, jmeter-plugins

> This question already has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55920108/3931900).

From past few days I am working with `jmeter`. It is working perfectly.

But today as I am trying to record a new script using `http` script recorder, when I am clicking on start, I am getting below exception..

```
java.io.IOException:   >> keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: DNSName components must begin with a letter <<
Command failed, code: 1
'keytool -genkeypair -alias 104.211.242.218 -dname "cn=104.211.242.218, o=JMeter Proxy (TEMPORARY TRUST ONLY)" -keyalg RSA -keystore proxyserver.jks -storepass {redacted} -keypass {redacted} -validity 7 -ext san=dns:104.211.242.218'
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.genkeypair(KeyToolUtils.java:171) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateSignedCert(KeyToolUtils.java:285) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateHostCert(KeyToolUtils.java:276) ~[jorphan.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initDynamicKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1540) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.initKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1447) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.startProxy(ProxyControl.java:530) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.startProxy(ProxyControlGui.java:569) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.gui.ProxyControlGui.actionPerformed(ProxyControlGui.java:424) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to a [bug in Java](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/security-dev/2017-March/015739.html) as there are a lot of domains which start with number like

- [9292.nl](https://9292.nl/)
- [9gag.com](https://9gag.com/)

So the options are in:

- Look for [Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) version which is not impacted, i.e. [JDK 8 u 151](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u151-relnotes-3850493.html)
- Use alternative recording solution like [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)

Comment: Another option is upgrading jmeter to 5.1 or above that jmeter resolved this problem.